# scipy generic_filter cast the returned values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, casting, scipy

With the code :

```
def stat_function(x):
    center = x[len(x) / 2]
    ecdf = ECDF(xx)
    percentile = (1 - ecdf(center)) * 100
    print percentile
    return percentile
```

## main :

```
print generic_filter(table,
    function=stat_function,
    size=window_size,
    mode=mode,
    extra_arguments=(-1,))
```

I got the output :

```
[[84 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 60]
[52 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 39]
[52 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 39]
[52 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 39]
[52 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 39]
[52 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 39]
[52 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 39]
[52 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 39]
[52 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 39]
[24 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15  0]]
```

Everything is fine but if i print "percentile' in my function before the return, i see that all my 15s are in fact 16.0s and my 39s are 40.0s. The function generic_filter require the return of a float and "16.0" is returned but in the built array, it's cast as an int and becomes "15". Indeed 
`print percentile, int(percentile)` will display "16.0, 15".
If someone could help me to understand why this scipy's function require a float then cast it into an int and why int(16.0) gives 15, i'm here.

PS : even with `numpy.array(generif_filter(...), dtype=numpy.float)`, i got the wrong table of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, the solution is tricky. Scipy will cast all values of the returned table in the type of your first table.
For exemple :

```
table = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
generic_filter(table, ... ) # returns a table of integers
table = numpy.array(table, numpy.float)
generic_filter(table, ... ) # returns this time a table of floats
```

So if like me scipy casts without reason his output, change your input ;)